# Hibernate for Java web application

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate with c3p0 (for connection pooling).

I have set my connection details using persistence.xml file. Here is my persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="LBSV1.0" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>xx.dataobject.CompanyDO</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/lbs?autoReconnect=true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="username"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.OSCacheProvider"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="1800"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300"/>
        <property name="c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select * from status"/>
        <property name="c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
        <property name="c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

The application is working fine. The application is fetching, inserting, deleting & updating the data. But if the application is left idle for more than 8 hrs then we get following error:

```
05 Feb 2013 19:40:25 49640738 [http-8080-8] ERROR root  - [SubscriberDataManager]****** Enable to get Subscriber Details due to : The last packet successfully received from the server was 49,165,385 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 49,165,386 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

The proposed "autoReconnect=true" is added in the URL. Also I googled regarding the connection timeout issue and added required property value in the "persistence.xml" file but still the error persists.

Here is the initialization log entry for c3p0:

```
06 Feb 2013 12:00:56 149355789 [http-8080-1] INFO  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource  - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PoolBackedDataSource@9263d39c [ connectionPoolDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource@77f9bf08 [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> true, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> z8kfsx8s1cc19kywfwqwq|1bdcbb2, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 300, initialPoolSize -> 5, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 1800, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 20, maxStatements -> 50, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 5, nestedDataSource -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource@7a7a7ef8 [ description -> null, driverClass -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> z8kfsx8s1cc19kywfwqwq|1b8737f, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://**.**.**.**:****/lbs?autoReconnect=true, properties -> {user=******, password=******, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto} ], preferredTestQuery -> select * from status, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> true, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false; userOverrides: {} ], dataSourceName -> null, factoryClassLocation -> null, identityToken -> z8kfsx8s1cc19kywfwqwq|68097d, numHelperThreads -> 3 ]
```

Can anyone tell me

1. what is wrong in my settings in persistence.xml file?
2. Or is Hibernate creating problem with the connection setting?

Comment: Do you mean JPA, rather than OpenJPA?

Comment: I am using OpenJPA jar for JPA. [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/) is the implementation of JPA by Apache Software Foundation.

Comment: I know what OpenJPA is, that is why I asked my question. In your persistence.xml it is quite obvious that you are using <provider>Hibernate</provider>, NOT OpenJPA.

Answer (score 0):

Its as if the connection pool has a reference to a connection, but when it actually tries to use it - the connection is found to be invalid!  :-O

So I think the database is timing out the connection and the connection pool knows nothing about it.

The one piece of text in your question might indicate the answer:

```
"is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'"
```

So I think you need to review the wait_timeout setting configured in your MySql.  Remember, your configureing connection pool sizes (eg hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20), but the MySql database has equivalent settings.  So (okay, not actually sure if there is an equivalent in MySql - just talking in principle here) if your MySql database is configured to only allow 10 connections - then the connection pool will never grow to your configured maximum size.

You can find the 'wait_timeout' setting in the MySql .cnf file you use.

Under Linux:

```
cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf | grep -i wait
```

The default is 28800 (8 hours) - so you need to increase it.  Let's think about this.  Say someone works till 5pm, and is back at work 8am the next day - that is already 15 hours.  So that can give you a guideline in terms of what value you need to set it to.

Aside - yes, it really sucks that there is an error being thrown to the application...  But yeah, I think its good practice to increase the wait_timeout.  Even if there wasn't an error being thrown:  Say you have a million people ;) coming to work at 8am...the implementation will most likely really struggle to acquire a million fresh connections in a few minutes (expensive operation) so in cases where many connections are involved one can't allow the connections to expire.

Some further notes on this I made when I encountered the same issue (but not relevant to your settings, but might be useful for others)

```
Database connections are managed by c3p0. The database must not prematurely timeout connections managed by c3p0.
    (a) "Check the system configuration on your database. MySQL has a wait_timeout setting which will close the connections idle over a period of time. If your idle_test_period and timeout are greater than MySQL wait_timeout (28800 seconds by default), your unused connections will have chance to be reset by MySQL server before tested or timed out by C3p0."
    (b) "Make sure the value here <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property> which is 100 is less than the wait_timeout set for mysql (by default it is 8 hrs
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know why the error is coming but I was perplexed because even after adding all the required setting it was still giving me the timeout error. I solved the error my adding `"debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces"` and `"hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period"`. These two setting dumped the stack log where the connection was not getting released in my application. Once that was fixed the application is not giving timeout error now.